# directshow, fails to renderstream connecting still pin to samplegrabber

Tags: image, graph, directshow, capture, screen-capture

have a problem with still pin capture,

we have a basic video and picture capturing project, capturing images and videos from capture pin is okay, but once i try to connect still pin (which is found succesfully by FindPin) to samplegrabber, it fails with hresult = E_FAIL/Unspecified failure/0x80004005,

the steps of the alrorythm is as follows (written in delphi, i have deleted the names of the variables):

- initializing interfaces, succesful search for the device, adding video capture filter;
- FindPin( 'capture filter' ,                  // Filter.
      PINDIR_OUTPUT,         // Look for an output pin.
      @PIN_CATEGORY_STILL,   // Pin category.
      Nil,                  // Media type (don't care).
      False,                 // Pin must be unconnected.
      0,                     // Get the 0'th pin.
      'still pin'                  // Receives a pointer to thepin.
      );
  this procedure finds pin succesfully;
- CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SampleGrabber, NIL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
  IID_IBaseFilter, 'sample grabber filter');
  succesful;
- 'sample grabber filter'.QueryInterface(IID_ISampleGrabber,
  'isamplegrabber object');
  succesful;
- 'graph builder'.AddFilter
  (VCOISampleGrabFilter, 'Sample Grabber');
  succesful;
- CoCreateInstance(CLSID_NullRenderer, NIL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
  IID_IBaseFilter, 'null renderer filter');
  succesful;
- 'graph builder'.AddFilter
  (VCONullRendererFilter, 'Null Renderer');
  succesful;
- 'isamplegrabber object'.SetBufferSamples(True);
  'isamplegrabber object'.SetOneShot(False);
  succesful;
- 'graph builder 2'.RenderStream
  (@PIN_CATEGORY_STILL, @MEDIATYPE_Video, 'video capture filter',
  'sample grabber filter', 'null renderer filter');
  there is where it is fails,
  after this alrotythm, if i look at the graph (have wrote the procedure for this), it looks like just 3 unconnected filters;

didn't use callback function for sample grabber, just get shots by using GetCurrentBuffer,

actually, this algorythm (only for capture pin) works alright,

algorythm was adopted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd318622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx,

also have tried another parameters for RenderStream, the same error occurs,

also tried using 'graph builder'.Connect function with 2 finded pins (out-still, in-samplegrabber), it also fails,

have anyone experienced the same? it is weird, at the first sight i thought that it is enough just to change PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE to PIN_CATEGORY_STILL and it will be fine,

the camera is 100% have working still pin (it is working with another programs),

i am rewriting microsoft's AmCap to try the same for now, but, unfortunately it is not finished yet,

thanks, 
igor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have found the solution for this problem, maybe someone will find this helpful: you should renderstream a renderer first, then a samplegrabber :)

Answer (score 0):

`RenderStream` is a wrapper method which [supposedly easily] connects stuff together into workable state. Unfortunately, the price for this is lack of detail for failures. You are interested in connecting pins directly using `IGraphBuilder.Connect` and isolating the failure to specific graph building step.